# [Full Text Search]Implement Full Text Search

Tags: c#, search, architecture

I am implementing full text search on a single entity, document which contains name and content. The content can be quite big (20+ pages of text). I am wondering how to do it.
Currently I am looking at using Redis and RedisSearch, but I am not sure if it can handle search in big chunks of text. We are talking about a multitenant application with each customer having more than 1000 documents that are quite big.

**TLDR: What to use to search into big chunks of text content.**

*This space is a bit unclear to me, sorry for the confusion. Will update the question when I have more clarity.*

Comment: What tech stack are you currently using?

Comment: The documents / content - how are they currently persisted?  (e.g. in database, flat file, etc)?

Comment: Тhe tech stack is .net core and mssql, The documents aren't persisted still, I am thinking of storing them in mssql as text field and caching them into Redis for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you what the right answer is, but I can give you some ideas about how to decide.

Normally if I had documents/content in a DB I'd be inclined to search there - assuming that the search functionality that I could implement was (a) functionally effect enough, (b) didn't require code that was super ugly, and (c) it wasn't going to kill the database.  There's usually a lot of messing around trying to implement search features and filters that you want to provide to the user - UI components, logic components, and then translating that with how the database & query language actually works.

So, based on what you've said, the key trade-offs are probably:

- Functionality / functional fit (creating the features you need, to work in a way that's useful).
- Ease of development & maintenance.
- Performance - purely on the basis that gathering search results across "documents" is not necessarily the fastest thing you can do with a IT system.

Have you tried doing a simple whiteboard "options analysis" exercise?  If not try this:

- Get a small number of interested and smart people around a whiteboard. You can do this exercise alone, but bouncing ideas around with others is almost always better.
- Agree what the high level options are.  In your case you could start with two: one based on MSSQL, the other based on Redis.
- Draw up a big table - each option has it's own column (starting at column 2).
- In Column 1 list out all the important things which will drive your decision.  E.g. functional fit, Ease of development & maintenance, performance, cost, etc.
- For each driver in column 1, do a score for each option.

How you do it is up to you: you could use a 1-5 point system (optionally you could use planning poker type approach to avoid anchoring) or you could write down a few key notes.

Be ready to note down any questions that come up, important assumptions, etc so they don't get lost.

Sometimes as you work through the exercise the answer becomes obvious.  If it's really close you can rely on scores - but that's not ideal.  It's more likely that of all the drivers listed some will be more important than others, so don't ignore the significance of those.